# How to append some data into existing xlsx sheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsx, read-write

I want to store my database information into **xlsx** file. I have created following program using python.

```
import xlsxwriter

def create_xlsx_file():
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/home/script/report.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    data = ['DataBase Name', 'Total Images', 'Gallary Name', 'Subject Name']

    r = 0
    c = 0
    for i in data:
        worksheet.set_column(c,c, 20)
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
        worksheet.write(r, c, i)
        c = c + 1

    workbook.close()

def add_info_into_file(DataBase_Name, Total_Images, Gallary_Name, Subject_Name):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/home/script/report.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    data = [DataBase_Name, Total_Images, Gallary_Name, Subject_Name]

    r = 2
    c = 0
    for i in data:
        worksheet.set_column(c,c, 20)
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
        worksheet.write(r, c, i)
        c = c + 1

    workbook.close()

create_xlsx_file()
add_info_into_file("msc", 100, "Mat", "rsp")
```

In above program, If I call `add_info_into_file()` function, then existing data truncated. So, how to append some data into existing sheet?

Please, someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can also use pandas

Comment: XlsxWriter does not support modifying or rewriting an existing file, see the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/introduction.html). Try OpenPyXL instead.

Comment: XlsxWriter is designed only as a file writer. It cannot read or modify an existing Excel file.

Answer (score 3):

`XlsxWriter` is designed only as a file writer. It cannot read or modify an existing Excel file.

You can use `openpyxl` for file appending.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active

rows = (
    (88, 46, 57),
    (89, 38, 12),
    (23, 59, 78),
    (56, 21, 98),
    (24, 18, 43),
    (34, 15, 67)
)

for row in rows:
    sheet.append(row)

book.save('appending.xlsx')
```

Comment: As written this appears to overwrite the `appending.xlsx` file instead of adding to it.